# How are recursive partition numbers found step by step on the program?

Tags: recursion, integer-partition, gap-system

The "**recursive partition numbers**" code written using GAP 4.10.2 are as follows.
For example, could you explain the working steps of the **GAP** **programming** for **nrparts(15)**? How did we get **nrparts (15) = 176** step by step in the program?

```gap
nrparts:= function(n)
local np;

np := function(n, m)
local i, res;
if n = 0 then
  return 1;
fi;
res:= 0;
for i in [1..Minimum(n,m)] do
  res:= res + np(n-i, i);
od;
return res;
end;

return np(n,n);

end;
```

Comment: This looks like a homework question to me, please have a look here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: I started to wonder. So let me open this question: what is the purpose of the variable m?

Comment: [See the explanation for this function in the GAP tutorial](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/tut/chap4.html#X7981E4197F7113EA)